# how to change the view of open files list in netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: netbeans

When I open, say a 10 or more file in Netbans 7.3.1 (windows 7), Netbeans puts each opened file's name in a a tab and all tabs are listed horizontally above the code eduitor. And at the end of that horizontal list, Netbeans provides clickable arrows (>,<,V ) to kind of navigate that list.

Since many times, the file that I want to get into is not visible in that horizontal tab list,  and I need to navigate to the left or right, I usually end up clicking on the down arrow (v) and that gives me the full list of all the open files. At that time, it's a simple click to go to that file. I wish that list was available to me in a vertical fashion without an extra step.

Is there a way to see that vertical list at all times? For example, where the HTML navigator is...

Comment: Put the window tabs to the right? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20598201/1329813

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe NetBeans can do this as you describe.

However, what you may find useful is Ctrl-Tab - pressing this once brings up the open file list and pressing Tab repeatedly iterates through these files. Ctrl-Shift-Tab iterates in the other direction. Letting go of Ctrl selects the currently selected file. This is similar to the Alt-Tab feature in Windows.

Hope this is useful.