# NetBeans moving tabs navigation to the right

Tags: java, netbeans

I've seen few people use it like that and Im struggling with figuring: how can i move the navigation of my open files inside NetBeans IDE to be navigating through a tool bar on the side.

In other words, instead of navigating between files horizontally (just like in the browser), i want the tabs to be displayed on my right on NetBeans.

Any chance someone could explain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No problem, just edited my post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299050/how-to-change-the-view-of-open-files-list-in-netbeans-7-3-1

Comment: That doesn't solve my issue

Answer (score 2):

You want to put the window tabs to the right side?
At Tools|Options|Misc|Windows set "Tab placement" to "right"

See also https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/upcoming_netbeans_feature_multi_row

[image: Upcoming NetBeans Feature: Multi-Row Editor Tabs! By Geertjan]

In **Netbeans 8** the tab placement options are in `Tools -> Options -> Appearance -> Document Tabs -> Tab placement`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey am not pretty sure about the Netbeans. If you see in the eclipse there is an short cut ctrl+f6 in order to change the you can directly go to editor settings and then you can change it to what ever you want.

If you come to net beans i saw in one of the post they mentioned ctrl+tab try to look this [link](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t102769.html) it might help you.

Thanks,

Comment: CTRL+Tab changes the tabs. I would like to move the entire navigation bar. Either CTRL+F6 not working.

Comment: for eclipse i got these two shortcuts try use these or else search for IE with the same search

Ctrl+F7 - Cycle to View
Ctrl+F8 - Cycle to Perspective

Comment: Its in the eclipse perspective what all the shortcuts i mentioned are . If you want them for netbeans you need to search equivalent shortcut.

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/Keyboard_Shortcuts you can use this link to find the shortcuts according to your version of netbeans.

Comment: Still can't find it, as far as i'm concerned, i don't mind finding a solution which is not a keyboard shortcut, i just wanna move this window erm.

Comment: Hey can you try this ..!!
Ctrl-Alt-PgUp / PgDown